# Is there any way to break a Protoss Sentry's Force Field?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

When I first encountered a Sentry force field, I expected to be able to attack and destroy it.  However, they don't seem to be targetable.  Is there anything I can do except wait for it to fade (assuming I can't just go around)?

Comment: Followup question - does the forcefield go away if the Sentry that created it dies?

Comment: @Peter nope.  Forcefields are unrelated to the Sentry that casts them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm glad you asked.

Massive units can break force fields by walking over them!

Enjoy the power of the Ultralisk, the Colossus and the Thor!

edit: its worth noting that you could burrow under force field with Roaches or Infestors.

Comment: I might be mistaken but can Roaches that are burrowed tunnel under them?

Comment: @Robb sorry for not addressing that, he originally asked about Breaking

Comment: My ultra can break a forcefield, head butt a neosteel bunker into rubble,  but still can't push a few zerglings out of the way when i want it to attack something :)

Comment: @Peter what's worse is the thing's Kaiser blades already reach over the Zerglings and touch the enemy.  Just swing the things damnit.

Comment: @tzenes - idle musing:   I guess giving ultra's the ability to walk over other units would sort of be stealing the Collossus' thunder a bit.  But maybe they could give zerglings the ability to run under massive units?  or just make the range of an ultra's attack "one zergling plus .00001"

Comment: Don't force fields also get sucked up by the mothership's vortex?

Comment: @Emmett yes, but this was not always the case.  It was patched in beta patch 17 to prevent Forcefield + Mothership abuse where you could force an infinite number of units onto a single tile for splash damage.

Comment: @Peter both have been suggested before.  Ultimately its how Blizzard decides to balance the interaction.  Certainly they've made Ultralisks a lot stronger than they were at the beginning of beta, but there is no telling which direct they want to take them now.

Comment: @tzenes - turns out they've decided to improve them by making them do less damage!  it's brilliant. Now i won't feel so bad when they aren't attacking, because I'll know that they wouldn't be doing a whole lot of damage anyway :)

Comment: @Peter yes, but did you see what they did for Siege tanks?

Comment: Archons can also break FF